# Copying canvas (which includes an image) to another canvas fails

Tags: javascript, canvas

What I'm trying to do: Draw an image (png) on a canvas, and then redraw/copy that canvas onto another canvas.

WHERE IT WORKS: If I draw the image (png) on a canvas, and just display that original canvas. It displays fine, including the random rectangle:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var image = new Image();
image.src ="./path/image.png";

image.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(image,tempCanvas.width/2,tempCanvas.height/2); 
}

ctx.fillRect(tempCanvas.width/2,tempCanvas.height/2,20,20); //random rectangle that also displays correctly

document.getElementById("placeholder2").appendChild(canvas);
```

WHERE IT FAILS: If I draw the image (png) on a canvas, and then try and draw that original canvas with the image onto another canvas, the image doesn't display, although the random rectangle, which was also drawn to the temp canvas displays fine:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'); //temp canvas
var tCTX = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
tempCanvas.width = canvas.width;

var image = new Image();
image.src ="./path/image.png";

image.onload = function(){
    tCTX.drawImage(image,tempCanvas.width/2,tempCanvas.height/2); //Draw the image to a temp canvas this time first
}

tCTX.fillRect(tempCanvas.width/2,tempCanvas.height/2,20,20); //Random rectangle also gets drawn to the temp canvas

ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas,canvas.width/2 - tempCanvas.width/2,canvas.height/2 - tempCanvas.height/2); //Now try and draw the temp canvas to the original canvas

document.getElementById("placeholder2").appendChild(canvas);
```

Not sure if I'm doing something stupid... or coming up against some sort of limitation? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is: when you draw the image on the `tempCanvas` you draw it from the center of the canvas. In this way only the first quarter of your image will be drawn on the bottom right corner of the `tempCanvas` Then you draw the `tempCanvas` on `canvas` from the center of this one. Your image is drawn but is drawn outside the `canvas`. Please try this:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
//wrap.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height= 300;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'); 
//wrap.appendChild(tempCanvas);//temp canvas
var tCTX = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
tempCanvas.width = canvas.width;
tempCanvas.height = canvas.height;

var image = new Image();
image.src = d.src;

image.onload = function(){
    tCTX.drawImage(image,0,0); //Draw the image to a temp canvas this time first


tCTX.fillRect(tempCanvas.width/2,tempCanvas.height/2,20,20); //Random rectangle also gets drawn to the temp canvas

ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas,0,0); //Now try and draw the temp canvas to the original canvas
}
document.getElementById("placeholder2").appendChild(canvas);
```

## UPDATE

The OP is commenting: *Hi Enxaneta, thanks for your suggestion! Gave it a try and still not quite working.* So I've decided to add a working example:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
//wrap.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height= 300;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'); 
//wrap.appendChild(tempCanvas);//temp canvas
var tCTX = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
tempCanvas.width = canvas.width;
tempCanvas.height = canvas.height;

var image = new Image();
image.src = d.src;

image.onload = function(){
    tCTX.drawImage(image,0,0); //Draw the image to a temp canvas this time first


tCTX.fillRect(tempCanvas.width/2,tempCanvas.height/2,20,20); //Random rectangle also gets drawn to the temp canvas

ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas,0,0); //Now try and draw the temp canvas to the original canvas
}
document.getElementById("placeholder2").appendChild(canvas);
```

```html
<div id="placeholder2">
<img id="d" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />
```

Comment: Hi Enxaneta, thanks for your suggestion! Gave it a try and still not quite working. I've tried playing with the placement of both the image and tempCanvas on main canvas to no avail. 

I actually included the random rectangle in the example, drawn in the same location as the image (which I can scale to same size as the random rectangle), to show that the "drawn to area" is actually in a visible area of the canvas. And the rectangle shows up in both instances, but in the second instance, the image doesn't appear while the rectangle still appears 

So it might not be a placement issue...?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I've updated my answer with a working example. The JS is the same as before. As a suggestion: please append the `tempCanvas` to the DOM to understand better what happens. Instead of drawing your image from the middle of the canvas try to draw it with a small offset, like 10 units - for example.

Comment: Hi Enxaneta, thank you for your help! It's working, although I now realize it's not a placement issue but rather my "drawing the tempCanvas to final canvas" was actually happening outside and after the image onLoad function. It also needed to be grouped inside the image onLoad function! Thanks again for your help!